Spring dynamic bean - @autowire, @import not invoked
Using spring "BeanDefinitionRegistry" register my custom bean ("SFTP" - shown below).
The custom bean has @value, @Autowired, @Bean annotation. The "@Bean("${service.name}_sftpTemplate")" annotation is not invoked during spring startup.

@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Slf4j
public class SFTP {

    @Value("${${service.name}.host}")
    String sftpHost;

    String serviceName;

    SFTP() {
        log.info("{} - sftp constructor" , System.getProperty("service.name"));
        this.serviceName = System.getProperty("service.name");
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbTemplate")
    String dbTemplate;

    @Bean("${service.name}_sftpTemplate")
    public String sftpConnectionAtBean(@Value("${service.name}") String serviceName) {
        log.info("{} - @Bean called", serviceName);
        return serviceName + "_sftpTemplate";
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Assert.notNull(dbTemplate, "DB Template is null");
        Assert.notNull(sftpHost, "SFTP host is null");
        Assert.isTrue(sftpHost.equals(serviceName + "_localhost"), "@value value is not matchec");
        log.info("{} - sftp service initalized with host - {}", serviceName, sftpHost);
    }
}

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sftp.db.store.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
    class SFTPJdbcConfig {

        SFTPJdbcConfig() {
            log.info("Inside SFTPJdbcConfig");
        }

        @Bean("dbTemplate")
        public String dbTemplate() {
            return "dbTemplate";
        }
    }

The '@ Bean("${service.name}_sftpTemplate")' in SFTP.java & " @ Bean("dbTemplate")" in  SFTPJdbcConfig.java is not initialized/called and this class is loaded via
    public static void registerBean(ApplicationContext context, String beanName, Class<?> beanClass) {
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(beanClass);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
    }

     // Bean registration dynamically
           registerBean(context,service +"SFTP", SFTP.class);
           context.getBean(service +"SFTP",SFTP.class);

// Failed 
        log.info("@Bean Git-SFTP -{}",context.getBean("git_sftpTemplate", SFTP.class) );


For the source refer to GIT Link - https://github.com/tamilsmani/spring-load-test
